# Let A and B be any propositional formula

Tags: boolean-algebra

How can I prove the following?

If $A$ is a tautology and $A\implies B$ is a tautology, then $B$ is a tautology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is a tautology and $A \Rightarrow B$ is a tautology. Is there a truth-value assignment $v$ that would make $B$ false ? If so, then, since $A \Rightarrow B$ is a tautology, for this $v$ we would have that $A$ should be false. But then we have found a truth-value assignment for which $A$ is false. This contradicts the assumption that $A$ is a tautology.

Comment: Ok but how can I prove it. The sentence that I wrote is a true sentence I have to prove that

Comment: My answer is a proof by contradiction of a statement "if $P$ then $Q$". I assume $P$ holds but also that $Q$ does not hold -- and use this to reach a contradiction. The contradiction tells us that the assumption, namely that $Q$ does not hold, cannot be true.

Comment: oh yes, that is true

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is a tautology means that $A$ is always true.

So if $A$ is true and $A\implies B$ is true, then $B$ is always true.

So $B$ is a tautology.

Comment: Ok, but I have to prove it, I already know what the text says.